# Binding to DoubleAnimation.To

Tags: wpf, storyboard

I wish to bind DoubleAnimation.To to a dependency property and trigger the animation when that property changes.  I can get the basic animation to work, but cannot figure out how to trigger it when the property changes.

The example shows me trying to animate Rectangle's Canvas.Left property.  Note that I have bound DoubleAnimation.To to Position.  I want the animation to run and move my rectangle when Position changes.  Can someone help me figure out the correct trigger?

```
<Viewbox>
<Canvas Height="200" Width="200">
    <Rectangle Name="MyRectangle" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="50" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Blue">
        <Rectangle.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard Name="MyStoryboard">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyRectangle" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                                            To="{Binding Position}" Duration="0:0:5" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Rectangle.Triggers>
    </Rectangle>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer is to use an EventTrigger and set its RoutedEvent property to Binding.TargetUpdated.  Also, you must add NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True to your binding (Position, in my case).

```
        <Viewbox>
        <Canvas Height="200" Width="200">
            <Rectangle Name="MyRectangle" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="50" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Blue">
                <Rectangle.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard Name="MyStoryboard">
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyRectangle" 
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                                                    To="{Binding Position, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Duration="0:0:5" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Rectangle.Triggers>
            </Rectangle>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
```